# discord has no attribute Intents once compiled

Tags: python, tkinter, discord, discord.py

So I'm making a GUI using Tkinter that one of the features is it launches a discord bot.
Now when I run the code within VS Code it all works fine. However when I compile it using pyinstaller I get an error saying "Module discord has no attribute Intents".
If I put the code for the bot in a separate python file and get the tkinter file to load the bot file using:

```
os.popen('py botcode.py')
```

Then compile the main tkinter file it all works BUT I want the code for the bot to be in the same file as the tkinter code and not two separate files.
Here is some of the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os, threading, json, collections
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Scrollbar, messagebox
from threading import Thread
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle
import re
import subprocess, sys, random, smtplib, string, ctypes
import requests, asyncio, functools

def getintents():
    return discord.Intents().all()

token = "BOT TOKEN HERE"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=",", intents=getintents())
status = cycle(['Running Gremlins App', 'Coded by Gremlin',])
client.remove_command('help')

def RandomColor(): 
    randcolor = discord.Color(random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF))
    return randcolor

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print('Online')

@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f'Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms', color=RandomColor())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

class Main_Page(Temp):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Temp.__init__(self, parent)

        botbut = tk.Button(self, button_stylesG, text='Start Bot',command=lambda:startbot())
        botbut.pack()

        def startbot():
            def sbot():
                client.run(token)
            botstart = Thread(target=sbot)
            botstart.start()
```

Why does it work when I run it through VS Code but not when compiled.
Why does it work when the bot code is in a separate file when compiled but not when in the same file?...

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you have file `discord.py` or folder `discord` and `import` loads this file/folder instead of module `discord` and it can't find `Intents` in your file. You have to rename this file/folder

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem you are facing may be due to your bot structure

So first go to https://discord.com/developers/applications

Select your bot

Click the options button
[image: OPTIONS BUTTON]

then go to `bot` scroll down and enable all intents
[image]

Comment: I have them all enabled on the dashboard. If I compile the gui python without the bot code within it but get the gui to open a separate python file that the bot code is in, it works fine. However if i include the code in the compiled gui it gives me the intents error

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
return discord.Intents.all()
```

and not

```
return discord.Intents().all()
```

or you could just do

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=",", intents=discord.Intents.all)
```

instead of

```
def getintents():
    return discord.Intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=",", intents=getintents())
```